# Почему словарь ключ:список заполняется в цикле одним последним списком, хотя ключи и списки уникальные?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

Надо создать словарь ключом в котором будет имя, а значением список строк, в котором присутствует это имя и индекс от 0 до 2:

```
{name : [url1+name+url2+0, url1+name+url2+1, url1+name+url2+2]}
```

Вот мой код:

```
def get_urls():
    """
        Returns a dictionary with each element being:
        {name : [url1+name+url2+0, url1+name+url2+1, url1+name+url2+2]}
    """
    url1 = "string1-"
    url2 = "-string2-"
    temp_l = [''] * 3
    names = ['alex', 'john', 'max', 'yen']
    main_dict = {}

    for name in names:
        for i in range(3):
            temp_l[i] = url1 + name + url2 + str(i)
        main_dict[name] = temp_l
        print(temp_l)
    return main_dict

dic = get_urls()
for d in dic:
    print(d, dic[d])
```

Если выводить список в каждой итерации цикла, получается:

```
['string1-alex-string2-0', 'string1-alex-string2-1', 'string1-alex-string2-2']
['string1-john-string2-0', 'string1-john-string2-1', 'string1-john-string2-2']
['string1-max-string2-0', 'string1-max-string2-1', 'string1-max-string2-2']
['string1-yen-string2-0', 'string1-yen-string2-1', 'string1-yen-string2-2']
```

Как и должно быть, но конечный словарь весь заполняется последним списком:

```
alex ['string1-yen-string2-0', 'string1-yen-string2-1', 'string1-yen-string2-2']
john ['string1-yen-string2-0', 'string1-yen-string2-1', 'string1-yen-string2-2']
max ['string1-yen-string2-0', 'string1-yen-string2-1', 'string1-yen-string2-2']
yen ['string1-yen-string2-0', 'string1-yen-string2-1', 'string1-yen-string2-2']
```

Так же  пробовал через 'main_dict.update' - результат такой же. Значения всех ключей заполняются последним списком.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ключевая ошибка в этой строке (в теле цикла `for name in names`):

```
main_dict[name] = temp_l
```

Вы до этого выделили в памяти список, обозначили его `temp_l`.

Потом чему-то присвоили, а потом **ссылку** на него присвоили элементу словаря.

В следующей итерации вы изменили список... В этот момент уже что-то идет не так.

Элемент словаря из прошлой итерации тоже поменялся. А в конечном итоге, все элементы словаря смотрят на одну и ту же область памяти.

**Решение:**

Делать копию списка, например, так:

```
main_dict[name] = temp_l[:]
```

Или любым другим способом, который можно найти в поисковике.

Comment: Спасибо за идею! Проблема решилась переносом объявления списка temp_l = [''] * 3 внутрь цикла for name in names:

Answer (score 3):

я бы посоветовал следовать ["Single-responsibility principle
"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) при написании функций:

```
def get_record(name, url1, url2, n=3):
    return [f"{url1}{name}{url2}{i}" for i in range(n)]

res = {name: get_record(name, url1, url2) for name in names}
```

результат:

```
In [291]: res
Out[291]: 
{'alex': ['string1-alex-string2-0',
  'string1-alex-string2-1',
  'string1-alex-string2-2'],
 'john': ['string1-john-string2-0',
  'string1-john-string2-1',
  'string1-john-string2-2'],
 'max': ['string1-max-string2-0',
  'string1-max-string2-1',
  'string1-max-string2-2'],
 'yen': ['string1-yen-string2-0',
  'string1-yen-string2-1',
  'string1-yen-string2-2']}
```